# Do I need to use NSTimer to get data from gyroscope iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer, gyroscope, core-motion

Right now I'm using the following code to get Euler values from the device's gyroscope. Is this how it's supposed to be used? Or is there a better way without using NSTimer?

```m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
CMMotionManager *motionManger = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
[motionManger startDeviceMotionUpdates];

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1/6) target:self selector:@selector(read) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)read {
CMAttitude *attitude;
CMDeviceMotion *motion = motionManger.deviceMotion;
attitude = motion.attitude;
int yaw = attitude.yaw; 
}
```

Comment: My goal is to continuously monitor the yaw value to determine if the device has rotated 360 degrees along its center. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use This...

```
    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
 {
     CMAttitude *attitude;
     attitude = motion.attitude;
     int yaw = attitude.yaw; 
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly to quote [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Handling Motion Updates at Specified Intervals
>
> To receive motion data
>   at specific intervals, the app calls a “start” method that takes an
>   operation queue (instance of NSOperationQueue) and a block handler of
>   a specific type for processing those updates. The motion data is
>   passed into the block handler. The frequency of updates is determined
>   by the value of an “interval” property.
>
> [...]
>
> Device motion. Set the deviceMotionUpdateInterval property to specify
>   an update interval. Call the or
>   startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:toQueue:withHandler: or
>   startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:withHandler: method, passing in a
>   block of type CMDeviceMotionHandler. With the former method (new in
>   iOS 5.0), you can specify a reference frame to be used for the
>   attitude estimates. Rotation-rate data is passed into the block as
>   CMDeviceMotion objects.

So e.g.

```
motionManger.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/6.0; // not 1/6; 1/6 = 0
[motionManager 
    startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
    withHandler:
        ^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
         {
             CMAttitude *attitude;
             attitude = motion.attitude;
             int yaw = attitude.yaw; 
         }];
```

I've lazily just used the main queue but that still may be a better solution than the NSTimer because it'll give the motion manager an explicit clue about how often you care to be updated.